# Place bullet points on new line

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this example of code:

https://jsfiddle.net/m0jux8k2/

I want to place the text with the bullets at synchronized position. But when I use text-align: center; the result is not visually good. 
So I tried this:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <ul>
       <li class="bullet-center-padding">&bull; Preferred</li>
       <li class="bullet-center-padding">&bull; Premium</li>
       <li class="bullet-center-padding">&bull; Premium Onsite</li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

But this is the visual result:

```
 • Preferred • Premium • Premium Onsite
```

How I can place every new bullet text on a new line?

Comment: By removing `display: inline-block` ? Also remove `li` default style using `list-style-type: none` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0jux8k2/2/)

Answer (score 6):

Remove `display: inline-block`. That will make them block elements.

> A block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element (container), thereby creating a "block". ([This article helps to explain what this means.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements))

Comment: Is there any other solution. Now the bullets are not synchronized?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, what do you mean by "synchronized"?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova apologies, didn't see your answer till i posted mine - removed mine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.Removed `"&bull;"` from html and " display: inline-block;" from css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      table,
      th,
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#A4A4A4">top text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" style="font-family:verdana; color:#424242">main list</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">list</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <ul>
                  <li class="bullet-center-padding">Preferred</li>
                  <li class="bullet-center-padding">Premium</li>
                  <li class="bullet-center-padding">Premium Onsite</li>
                </ul>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" style="font-family:verdana; color:#424242">main list</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>for test one</td>
              <td>and test second</td>
              <td>1 test threee</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <ul>
                  <li class="bullet-center-padding">Preferred</li>
                  <li class="bullet-center-padding">Premium</li>
                  <li class="bullet-center-padding">Premium Onsite</li>
                </ul>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <ul>
                  <li class="bullet-center-padding">Preferred</li>
                  <li class="bullet-center-padding">Premium</li>
                  <li class="bullet-center-padding">Premium Onsite</li>
                </ul>
              </td>
            </tr>



          </table>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#D8D8D8">bottom text</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.bullet-center-padding {

  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

[Demo JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/m0jux8k2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did with your css code just update it with yours

```
    .bullet-center-padding {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m0jux8k2/4/)